# using Bootstrap Datatable, Rows get empty when trying to print

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Actually i want to use Print button on Datatable. I can achieve that too.. When clicking print button, it is showing the Print view, But the tbody gets empty.. there is no rows at all..

My Code is below :

```
                $("#Book").dataTable().fnDestroy();
                oTable = $('#Book').dataTable({
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "aButtons": [
                        "copy",
                        "print",
                        {
                            "sExtends": "collection",
                            "sButtonText": "Save",
                            "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                });

                <table id="Book" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" style="padding-top: 100px">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column 1</th>
                            <th>Column 2</th>
                            <th>Column 3</th>
                            <th>Column 4</th>
                            <th>Column 5</th>
                            <th>Column 6</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
```

Then i am having print button on the output like this

[image: Before Print View]

but after clicking print button, it is not showing any rows like this

[image: After Print View]

Here if i click save button itself, it is not saving in any format.

Please help me out from this issue..

Comment: can you share some code or fiddle ??

Comment: I am a beginner and i dont know how to add my code in fiddler.. Can you share you email address and i will send you the file

Comment: yashx1 [at] gmail [dot] com